# Assigning var to var in C

Tags: c, if-statement, variable-assignment, var, assign

```
float p, q, x1, x2;

p=(-b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
q=(-b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);

if(p<q){
    p=x1;
    q=x2;
}

else{
    p=x2;
    q=x1;
}
```

I want to assign these values if the conditions are true, however, I get only 0 values from x1 and x2.

Can you point out where I'm wrong?

Comment: there, I have edited it

Comment: You never assign anything to `x1` or `x2`, so they could contain anything.

Comment: what happens when a=1, b=0, c=1?

Comment: Voting to close since this is just a typo-level bug:  `p` and `q` should be `x1` and `x2` in the initial assignments and the comparison.  Also, it should check for imaginary solutions rather than calling `sqrt` with a negative argument.

Comment: @TomKarzes That's the point, I want to assign p or q to x1 or x2 so I can use it later on in my code, why can't I do it this way?

Comment: @Ben Ok, in that case your assignments are backwards:  Change `p=x1` to `x1=p` etc.  Remember, `a=b` copies `b` to `a`, not the other way around.  The right side is assigned to the left side.

Comment: @TomKarzes That's exactly what I wanted to accomplish. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ben Ok, glad you worked it out!

Comment: @Ben do you know how to use a debugger? That sounds like the most important thing for you to learn right now. You don't have to be scratching your head in mystery and asking for help when you don't understand where your code is going wrong. With a debugger, you can step through your code, statement by statement, and immediately see all of your variable values after each step. Let us know what operating system, editor, and C compiler you are using, and I or someone else can recommend a good debugger that will work for you.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I'm using the default one with codeblocks, it only told me that I had a "statement with no effect". If you have better suggestions for a debugger, I'd gladly accept.

Comment: @Ben I'm happy to help with some recommendations - but first let me know what operating system you are using on your computer, since that will determine what's available for you.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Cool, in that case the choice is simple: [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/). When you run the installer it will bring up a screen of "Workloads". Scroll down and turn on "Desktop development with C++". You can add others later or now if you want (.NET, Python, etc.). When you run Visual Studio, create a new project with File/New/Project and choose Visual C++/Windows Desktop/Windows Console Application. Then follow [this debugging tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/06/23/c-tutorial-debugging-overview/) using your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float p, q, x1, x2;

p=(-b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
q=(-b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);

if(p<q){
    x1=p;
    x2=q;
}

else{
    x2=p;
    x1=q;
}
```

I think you are trying to calculate p and q using some math formulae and then assigning them to x1 and x2. However the way you are doing the assignment is reverse. So I've corrected it. Hope it helps.